# Flutter: Focus next TextFormField does not work in Modal

Tags: flutter, keyboard, focus

I'd like to focus the next TextFormField, when the user presses the next-button on the keyboard.
But, when I press the next-button, the keyboard just disappears. No Focus.
Is that problem there, because of the ShowModalBottomSheet-Function?

How can I fix it?

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (builder) {
          return addSheet(this);
        });
```

```
Container addSheet(State state){

  return new Container(
    height: 400.0,
    color: Color(0xFF737373),
    child: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(8.0), topRight: const Radius.circular(8.0))),
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: new Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Mushroom Type',
                      hintText: 'Golden Oysters'
                  ),
                  autofocus: true,
                  focusNode: _mushroomTypeFocus,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                    FocusScope.of(state.context).requestFocus(_cultureTypeFocus);
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Culture Type',
                      hintText: 'liquid culture, bag culture'
                  ),
                  focusNode: _cultureTypeFocus,
                )
              ]
            ),

        )
    )
  );
}

final FocusNode _mushroomTypeFocus = new FocusNode();
final FocusNode _cultureTypeFocus = new FocusNode();
```

[image]

Comment: Wrap your container in singleChildViewScroll widget. It will work

Comment: That does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Requested focus in initState worked for me.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  myFocusNode = FocusNode();
  myFocusNode.requestFocus();
}
```

Also, the `autofucus:true` is not needed since you are using the `focusNode`